# The Perfect Bridge

Tags: statics, building-physics

Is it possible to calculate the amount of weight a perfectly designed bridge(not necessarily known) can hold given certain parameters and under ideal and perfect conditions:

- amount and type of wood
- atmospheric conditions
- length the bridge must be

Comment: I flagged this for closure as "too broad", but it's also mainly an engineering question and so is probably off-topic as well.

Comment: The Physics answer to this question is "use Statics to analyze bridge designs", though there's not much to say about it in an open-ended design question.  To get more physical equations and such, you'd want a specific design and parameters to focus on.

Comment: I don't think "perfect bridge" is well defined in this context.  What constitutes "perfect"?  Is it just a beam with fixed supports on the ends?  What constitutes "holding"?  Is it supporting without total structural failure, or does "holding" actually mean hold up without a certain threshold of displacement?  There is a lot that is unclear and extremely broad about this question.

Comment: The answer to this is no, because you can't define what 'perfect' means.  As an example, consider a girder which is designed to support compressive loads.  Such a thing has an inherent instability: it will buckle under load if perturbed enough.  But how much perturbation should you allow?  You can always use less material -- or equivalently make the structure 'stronger' by reducing stability.  Is a bridge with no stability margin at all 'perfect'?  I would not like to use such a thing.

Comment: To the question actually asked, "is it possible to calculate...." the answer is very simple: YES. This is what any bridge designer is supposed to do, before the bridge is even built. He may be doing it well or badly, but most bridges stand up so they may be doing it quite right. Of course, the actual bridge, as any construction, will be designed with some safety factor so it can hold a lot more than expected to actually happen in practice.

Answer (score 1):

[Statics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statics) is the field of analyizing stresses and forces on stationary solid objects, like what you're asking about.  It becomes [Dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_dynamics) when stuff starts moving.

Early Mechanical Engineering classes in college show how to use Statics to do stuff like calculate the load that a structure like a bridge can handle.  This sort of analysis is used to inform structural design.

Ultimately you'll need to consider a lot of factors, like:

- available materials and their costs;
- expected load on the bridge;

  - Bridge for people to walk over a stream?
  - Ten lanes of highway traffic with lots of trucks?
- any weather/natural concerns;

  - Hurricanes?
  - Earthquakes?
  - Godzilla attacks?
- special design constraints to fit the particular application;

  - Does it need to be a certain height to allow ships under it?
  - Does it need to open up?
- where it can draw support from.

  - Is it over a shallow river that supports can go into?
  - Is it over a deep chasm?
  - How stable is the ground in the area?

Once you have all of those factors together, and presumably a lot more, you can select appropriate numeric values for your various designs and their parameters using [optimization techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization), typically with the assistance of a [CAD program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_design) to do the modeling.

In the end, the question is usually about how to get the best trade-off between cost and desirability.